# Java serialization, Can I change the datatype of the variable?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I need to change the datatype of the `quantity` field while serialization and de-serialization.`

`Double` to `Integer` in `writeObject();`

`Integer` to `Double` in `readObject();`

**Item class**

```
class Items implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1537402844776823455L;

    Double quantity;

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream o) throws IOException {
        PutField field = o.putFields();
        field.put("quantity", quantity.intValue());
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        GetField field = stream.readFields();

        if((field.get("quantity", new Double(0)) instanceof Integer)){
            quantity = ((Integer) field.get("quantity", new Integer(0))).doubleValue();
        }else if((field.get("quantity", new Double(0)) instanceof Double)){
            quantity = (Double) field.get("quantity", new Double(0));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but quantity is always double while de-serialization.

`quantity` field must be `Double` in class and `Integer` in serialized object.
Is this is possible with Serialization.

Comment: Why? You will lose both precision and range.

Comment: Server will receive two type of serialized object one with quantity field Double another with  Integer, At Server side need to de-serialize both request and cast to double.

Answer (score 0):

Try java.lang.Number.
Integer and Double extends it.